# use my vmware ubuntu as a non-virtual OS

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-fusion

I like ubuntu. For lots of my development work its far less of a hassle than compiling software on osx. Is there any shot of moving my existing ubuntu vm to my hard drive? That would shave quite a bit of time getting comfortable again... I've seen some docs describing the process, but its [windows only...](http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/doc/V2P_TechNote.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really easy to just copy your home directory over via ssh file transfer, or anther file copy method.  In fact, there is a blog with [3 simple steps to move to another Ubuntu computer](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/).  Great script there for getting a list of all your PPA's and other packages installed.

This is also one of the first ideas suggested on the [Ubuntu Brainstorm site](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/1/).  There are some good comments in there as well.

Comment: terrific, that's some precise and succinct advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can save your whole home directory, make sure all hidden files/folders are transferred. But you'll have to install the programs and packages again as they may have been scattered around the whole os and would be extremely long to get it how you want.